# LUKS with encrypted /boot + GRUB -> rescue shell 50% of the time

Tags: grub2, encryption, luks, 20.04, cryptsetup

I just setup xubuntu 20.04 according to the [full disk encryption howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019) on a 32GB usb drive. I used 5000 iterations for the encryption, sha256. The first time, I restarted after installation, grub asked for my password, but then dropped me into the rescue shell after some time (timeout?) and the first command in the shell was my (correct) password in clear text. I was stumped, so I booted back into the installation medium, chroot'ed into the manually unlocked stick, checked everything was ok. After rebooting into the target thumb drive, I again got pushed to the rescue shell. I then tried to manually do `cryptomount (hd0,gtp2)`, which to my surprise worked. Then however I didn't know how to continue and again rebooted.

This time however, suddenly, grub would successfully boot into xubuntu, which got me even more confused. On subsequent reboots, I noticed that I can successfully boot maybe 30-50% of the time and the rest of the time I get thrown into the rescue shell. What might be a possible explanation for this?

My current guess is that grub is not fast enough with decrypting and therefore I hit a timeout, unless I'm lucky. But shouldn't i get some error message at least?